# Computer freezes often (and always under certain circumstances)

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, malware

I have experienced a lot of issues with freezing in my computer. At first, I had to disable Superfetch and Windows Update because these services would cause - and still cause - this shortly after starting up Windows. Occasional freezes still happened, but it was bearable for me. But it seems that over time these occurrences increased... Since a little time ago, I cannot start Internet Explorer 11 because this also causes a freeze. After inspection, I saw that the Users/.../.../Windows/Cookies folder will cause a freeze as soon as I perform any action on it (double click or right-click). This also happens in Windows safe mode. And more unfortunately, when I run any program that manipulates files, such as CCleaner and many malware scanners, the computer will freeze again... Not all the antivirus software that I tested will trigger a freeze, but unfortunately they will not find the cause either. I suspect that the problem is caused by malware, but I really need some advice here, other than "format your hard drive". Thank you...

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: I have just installed HD Tune Pro and I see a lot of things there... Which results exactly should I report here?

Comment: All of them....

Comment: When I run an error scan the computer freezes after reaching a certain position (always the same position). In the Health tab I get everything OK except a warning for 116 unstable sectors in Current Pending Sector. I will continue doing some other tests now...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad sector on your hard drive. I've had this issue and that was the problem. Every time any software tries to access that point on your drive it doesn't do well with it...

Try

1. Right click on your hard drive
2. select Properties
3. choose the Tools tab
4. select Check – scan drive

Comment: I have recently scanned and automatically repaired bad sectors in my hard disk but the problem persists...

Comment: Ok, good, I believe that we found the initiation of the problem. You dealt with the bad sections but the bad sectors had information in them and if it was critical, and couldn't be retrieved to be moved elsewhere, it is, to the software, as if the issue persists. You'll need to repair the software too. Try running a repair on your Windows OS and other software as needed. But really, you need to replace that drive. I would suggest doing that and a fresh install. Back up your files first of course